# Problemas consulta eloquen laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo dos tablas, una llamadas usuarios y otra users, he realizado la consulta directamente a mysql.

```
SELECT COUNT(nombre), usuario_ad, name, last_name 
FROM usuarios, users 
where usuario_ad=username 
GROUP BY usuario_ad;
```

la cual funciona bien, las columnas last_name y name son de la tabla users, mientras que usuario_ad y count(nombre) son de usuarios.

El problema esta cuando quiero pasar esto a eloquen, ya que he tratado de unir dos tablas con esta dinaminca pero me ha causado problemas.

```html
DB::table('usuarios')
              ->select('usuario_ad', DB::raw('count(nombre) as nombre'))
              ->groupBy('usuario_ad')
              ->orderBy('nombre', 'desc')
              ->paginate(10);
```

Esta consulta funciona bien para una sola tabla, como puedo adaptarla a la consulta mysql de dos tablas que mostre arriba?

users

```html
    $table->increments('id');
            $table->foreign('tipos_usuarios_id')->references('id')->on('tipos_usuarios');
   $table->string('name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('username',15)->unique();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
   $table->unsignedInteger('tipos_usuarios_id');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

usuarios

```html
Schema::create('usuarios', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->string('usuario_ad')->nullable();
            $table->string('nombre')->required();
            $table->string('apellido')->required();
            $table->integer('cedula')->required()->unique();
            $table->string('telefonos')->required();
            $table->string('direccion')->required();
            $table->string('barrio')->required();
            $table->string('lugar_votacion')->required();
            $table->string('mesa_votacion')->required();
            $table->string('email')->required()->unique();;
            $table->string('ciudad')->required();
            $table->string('asignacion')->nullable();
            $table->string('estado')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

SOLUCION

```html
   $conteo = DB::table('usuarios')
              ->join('users', 'usuarios.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
              ->select('usuario_ad', 'name', 'last_name', DB::raw('count(nombre) as nombre'))
              ->groupBy(['usuario_ad', 'name', 'last_name'])
              ->orderBy('nombre', 'desc')
              ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Pues que solo son dos campos de otra tabla.. no se en que podra ayudar las estructuras completas... sin embargo ahi las subi.

Comment: si tan solo aplicas groupBy a todas las columas que seleccionas, asi: ->groupBy(['usuario_ad','nombre'])

Comment: Si shassain,  en el groupBy y en el select,  actualice tambien la solucion, gracias por sus sugerencias, y disculpa shadow, esto es realmente amplio y estresante.